# Ext between different skyscraper sheaves on $\mathbb P^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I would like to understand the first Ext group
$$
\operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^n}} (\mathcal O_x, \mathcal O_y)
$$
when $x$ and $y$ are two different points and $\mathcal O_x$ and $\mathcal O_y$ are the skyscraper sheaves associated to them. I have found a calculation using a locally free resolution of $\mathcal O_x$ (coming from the Koszul resolution) in [theses lecture notes](https://people.math.harvard.edu/%7Eauroux/18.969-S09/mirrorsymm-lect16.pdf), but I'm not sure, whether the same argument holds if one considers two different points. (On affine $n$-space, I believe the above Ext group should vanish.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are distinct points on **any** variety $X$ then
$$
\mathrm{Ext}^p(\mathcal{O}_x,\mathcal{O}_y) = 0
$$
for any $p$. One way to prove this is to use the (derived) pullback-pushforward adjunction for the embedding $i \colon \{y\} \to X$ and the fact that
$$
Li^*\mathcal{O}_x = 0
$$
because the support of $\mathcal{O}_x$ does not contain $y$.